# javascript href property not showing or enabled after change made

Tags: javascript

I have a few pages to load and used the following JavaScript to load them on a onclick event :

Here is my code

```
var varUrl = "./MobileMenus/MainMenu.aspx";            
window.location.href = varurl;
```

After updates was run on my laptop I cannot use the above script anymore it just does not show the **href** property after I type the location to call the href property. When putting it in a alert box it display as Invalid. On VS2012 it works fine but not on VS2008 any more.

How can i do this ?

Comment: You need to provide the full code.. including the click events and all..

Answer (score 2):

You missed the variable casing, it should be

```
window.location.href = varurl; <-- before

window.location.href = varUrl; <-- now
```

try that